# Sphero orbBasic can't update firmware

Tags: sphero-api

Looking at the reading in the orbBasic app, my Sphero's oB FW isn't updating.  It's still at 1.45/1.6, even after forcing updates.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of this answer, 1.45/1.6 is the current Firmware/Bootloader version of Sphero.

Comment: Oh, so oB 1.7 isn't released yet?  I saw it on the last page of the oB doc, so I was curious.

Comment: I think that is referencing the version of orbBasic that is shipped along with the firmware, not the bootloader.